# How to get Web Api to publish web.config with verb request filtering

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, iis-10, requestfiltering

When i publish my .net 6 web api it creates a web.config that looks like this (redacted)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\MyDomain.MySubdomain.MyApp.Web.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess">
        <environmentVariables>
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
        </environmentVariables>
      </aspNetCore>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

I then need to enter into IIS-10 for the site and under requestfiltering add the verb DELETE as allowed - After which it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\MyDomain.MySubdomain.MyApp.Web.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess">
        <environmentVariables>
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
        </environmentVariables>
      </aspNetCore>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
      <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <verbs>
                    <add verb="DELETE" allowed="true" />
                </verbs>
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Currently i must remember to add the delete verb every times i update the application.

The web.config does not exists in my project its only created when i publish. It seems that ex. ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT line comes from my launchsettings (i am guessing), but i cannot find a similar method to have the requestfiltering added to the web.config.

launchsettings:

```
  "profiles": {
    "MyDomain.MySubdomain.MyApp.Web": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7085;http://localhost:5085"
    },
```

Comment: If I understand your issue correctly, you are looking for a way to configure allow HTTP verbs either in launch.json  or anywhere in asp.net core project so that you don't need to configure that every time you publish the project, right?

Comment: @md-farid-uddin-kiron Yes, any methode really, either appsettings, launchsettings, publishprofiles or something else - while i hope for an answer here, i am looking into just adding the web.config to the project and hoping some sort of auto merge happens.